# Saving the stream using Intel RealSense

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, intel, realsense

I'm new to Intel RealSense. I want to learn how to save the color and depth streams to bitmap. I'm using C++ as my language. I have learned that there is a function ToBitmap(), but it can be used for C#.

So I wanted to know is there any method or any function that will help me in saving the streams.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also working my way through this, It seems that the only option is to do it manually. We need to get ImageData from  PXCImage. The actual data is stored in ImageData.planes but I still don't understand how it's organized.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/dipping-into-the-intel-realsense-raw-data-stream?language=en Here you can find example of getting depth data. 
But I still have no idea what is pitches and how data inside planes is organized.

Here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-perceptual-computing-sdk/topic/332718 kind of backwards process is described.

I would be glad if you will be able to get some insight from this information.
And I obviously would be glad if you've discovered some insight you can share :).

**UPD:** Here is something that looks like what we need, I haven't worked with it yet, but it sheds some light on internal organization of planes[0] https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-perceptual-computing-sdk/topic/514663

**UPD2:** To add some completeness to the answer:
You then can create GDI+ image from data in ImageData:

```
auto colorData = PXCImage::ImageData();

if (image->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24, &colorData) >= PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
    auto colorInfo = image->QueryInfo();
    auto colorPitch = colorData.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcBYTE);
    Gdiplus::Bitmap tBitMap(colorInfo.width, colorInfo.height, colorPitch, PixelFormat24bppRGB, baseColorAddress);
}
```

And Bitmap is subclass of Image (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462(v=vs.85).aspx). You can save Image to file in different formats.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you were. I'm very new to the technology and to the language. The links are very much helpful. Thank you very much.