# PXCAccelerator is undefined

Tags: intellisense, intel, realsense

Hi I am trying to load an extern image into a `PXCImage` object. I pretend to use this function:

```
void LoadImageFromLocal(PXCSession* session, PXCImage **dst_img, const char * path)
{
  IplImage *image = cvLoadImage(path);
  unsigned char *rgb_data;
  int rgb_pitch = image->widthStep; // bytes between image lines

  rgb_data = (unsigned char*)image->imageData;
  PXCAccelerator * accelerator;
  session->CreateAccelerator(PXCAccelerator::ACCEL_TYPE_CPU, &accelerator);

  PXCImage::ImageInfo info;
  memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
  info.height = image->height;
  info.width = image->width;
  info.format = PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24;

  PXCImage::ImageData data;
  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  data.format = PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB24;
  data.planes[0] = rgb_data;
  data.pitches[0] = rgb_pitch;

  pxcStatus sts = accelerator->CreateImage(&info, 0, &data, dst_img);
}
```

But in my code the `PXCAccelerator` class appears as undefined. I am using this libraries: `#include "pxcsensemanager.h"` and `#include "pxcemotion.h"`. I have the 2014 RSSDK version. What library should I use to access to the `PXCAccelerator` class?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the PXCAccelerator was part of the (now deprecated) Intel Perceptual Computing SDK, but doesn't exist in the Intel RealSense SDK.

Now you should use [`PXCSession::CreateImage`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?createimage_pxcsession.html) instead:

```
    PXCImage* CreateImage(PXCImage::ImageInfo *info, PXCImage::ImageData *data);
```

Comment: Yes I've found that PXCAccelerator is not available any more. Do you know where I can find an example of how to do this?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but I'd guess you'd only have to change your last line to `dst_img = session->CreateImage(&info, &data);` or something like that.

Comment: 0k, I've started a bounty in a question similar to this one, but at the beginning I was confused and at the edge of desperation so I didn't realize that the question is too different of what I want. If you post some stuff [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174076/how-to-save-an-image-in-intel-realsensevisual-c) I will give you the bounty.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask your help for [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/realsense/topic/606665#comment-1855954), Regards